# How to setup Xdebug for remote debugging a PHP Google App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, xdebug

I want to remotely debug my PHP Google App Engine app with Xdebug. In Visual Studio, I set launch.json to:

```
"name": "Listen for XDebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"port": 9090,
"pathMappings": {
  "/": "${workspaceRoot}/" // remote / local
  }
```

Set local php.ini to:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port = 9090
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Installed Xdebug helper for Chrome extension.

I set a breakpoint in a script and launched the debug. When I visit the script with my browser, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using GAE Standard or Flexible? Also what PHP version are you using on your app?

Comment: Using GAE Standard PhP 7.2. The way I understand it now, is that GAE cannot have xdebug running. Only my local dev environment. So I use extensive logging on GAE to see whats going on in my code.

Comment: That is correct you can use XDebug with your local development server on PHP 5 as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server). For PHP 7 the proper way of debugging your app would be to write application logs as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/writing-application-logs).